# Chrome Extension Dev Channel Downloads Permissions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

With `Chrome Version 27.0.1448.0 dev` while attempting to call

```
chrome.downloads.download(url:song.url);
```

I receive the error `chrome.downloads is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json.`

My permissions look like.

```
"permissions": [
    "downloads",
    "https://*/*", "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is an experimental feature, so you may need to request "experimental" permission as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response however it is enabled.